# Installed statsmodels successfully but no module found error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels

I successfully installed statsmodels using this command `!pip install statsmodels` but when I import it can show an error module not found.

[image]

**Note:** Error occur in VsCode when I run in Jupyter Notebook its fine. I want to deploy it so it can be necessary to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it can be the most common problem: you have two Pythons installed and `pip` install modules for one Python, but you run code with other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. If you run code with `python script.py` then you can use `python -m pip install...` . Or run in code `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter) and choose the correct interpreter.

Python is an interpreted language, and in order to run Python code and get Python IntelliSense, you must tell VS Code which interpreter to use.

From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening **the Command Palette** (Ctrl+Shift+P), start typing the `Python: Select Interpreter` command to search, then select the command. You can also use the **Select Python Environment** option on the Status Bar if available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too):

[image]